# Package babel Error: Unknown language `francais'

Tags: errors, babel

I updated TexLive today, and it has updated French language successfully according to the utility:
[image]

However I have a typesetting problem that did not appear before, with the command
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

Namely
*./struct_effectivite.tex:112: Package babel Error: Unknown language `francais'.

Either you have

(babel)                misspelled its name, it has not been installed,

(babel)                or you requested it in a previous run. Fix its name,

(babel)                install it or just rerun the file, respectively. In

(babel)                some cases, you may need to remove the aux file.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.

Type  H   for immediate help.*

Note that the same error message appears if I put instead
\usepackage[french]{babel}
(literally! It says *Unknown language 'francais'* and not *Unknown language 'french'*).

How can I correct this problem?

Upon request, here is an example with its log file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{smfart}
\usepackage{amscd,verbatim}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Bla bla bla.

\end{document} 

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test-babel.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-10-27> xparse <2020-03-03>
(/Users/kahn/Library/texmf/tex/latex/smfart.cls
Document Class: smfart 2000/11/20 v1.3 Classe LaTeX pour les articles publies p
ar la SMF
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amscd.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/french.ldf))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/scalefnt.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latin1.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test-babel.aux)

./test-babel.tex:7: Package babel Error: Unknown language `francais'. Either yo
u have
(babel)                misspelled its name, it has not been installed,
(babel)                or you requested it in a previous run. Fix its name,
(babel)                install it or just rerun the file, respectively. In
(babel)                some cases, you may need to remove the aux file.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 \begin{document}
                    
? 
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./test-babel.aux) ){/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-supe
r/cm-super-t1.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-sup
er/sfrm0900.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super
/sfrm1200.pfb>
Output written on test-babel.pdf (1 page, 12148 bytes).
SyncTeX written on test-babel.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test-babel.log.
```

Comment: Please show a full example including a log

Comment: your rather old class seem to call francais. Try `\babelprovide[import=fr]{francais}` after loading babel.

Comment: It works. Thank you. Why is it needed now and not before?

Comment: I think (but didn't check) that babel cleaned up the language names a bit, for historical reasons french was a bit of a mess (francais, french, frenchb ...)

Comment: Ulricke Fischer you are right, but they had cleaned this up since at least the 2016 release. And the problem arose both with [francais]{babel} and [french]{babel}, as I explained. (And is solved in both cases by daleif's suggestion, as I just checked.)

Comment: The smflatex package is part of CTAN (current v.1.5d 2018, your issue is fixed) but not of TeXLive (for copyright reasons I guess), so you have to install it by yourself in texmf-local or so… and run the risk of having an outdated version as it happened for you.  You should get in touch with the maintainer (Antoine Chambert-Loir) the copyright restrictions are probably not intended…

Comment: After exchanging with Chambert-Loir, the problem was indeed due to an old version of smflatex, and disappears with the current version 1.5d. Thank you!